# Trouble applying CSS to programatically created Pane on MouseEvent

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I have a stack pane that when the mouse enters, I create a pane, stick some text in it, and display it near the mouse.

StatisticsController.java

```
 stackPane.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            Pane pane = new Pane();
            Text text = new Text("Example Text");

            //Add the text to the pane and set it near the mouse
            pane.getChildren().add(text);
            pane.setLayoutY(event.getSceneY() - 50);
            pane.setLayoutX(event.getSceneX() - 100);

            //add the  style class to give it a blueBG background
            pane.getStyleClass().add("blueBG");

            // add it too our root
            getRoot().getChildren().add(pane);
});
```

As you can see below when the Pane and text appear when I roll over the stackPane (the black circle and question mark in the image).

[image]

However it doesn't have the blue background I'm looking for.

What I find strange is if instead of adding it to the root and I add it to an existing Vbox, it styles correctly (Here I roll over the same stackPane):

[image]

So:

```
 //Styles Correctly
 getInfoBox().getChildren().add(pane);

// Adds but does not style
getRoot().getChildren().add(pane);
```

Some things that may be worth noting:

1)getInfoBox() is a static getter. I have multiple controllers which extend a MasterController which has static instance variables to things all controllers would want to be able to access - like the infoBox, to display information.

2)The root is a BorderPane made in the Main class:

Main.java

```
//Create the root
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

// I've cut it out to save space but this repeats 4 times to set 
//an .fxml file for the top, left, right and bottom of the borderPane ///
FXMLLoader headerLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/header.fxml"));
Parent headerRoot = headerLoader.load();
root.setTop(headerRoot);
//------------------------------------------//

//Set the static reference in the MasterController
MasterController.setRoot(root);

Scene scene = new Scene(root,1366,768);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

3) The css files are all declared in the .fxml files using Scene Builder. The top, bottom, left, right .fxml files all have the same css (main.css). So does the statistic.fxml which is loaded on button click into the center (you can see in the image)

Suggestion: Could it be because the CSS is not defined for the Scene or BorderPane itself, it only applies to nodes added into the borderPane sections? If so how would I go about letting the enter Scene/Stage use the same css and would that negate adding in the css to each .fxml?

Edit:

When adding this code to the main to apply the CSS to the scene:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(root,1366,768);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/css/main.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
```

I get this:

[image]

So the CSS for the text is now working, but not for the Pane? I have no idea why this might happen.

// ---- REPRODUCTION -- //

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();

        MasterController.setRoot(bp);

        Parent left = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("left.fxml"));
        Parent right = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("right.fxml"));

        bp.setLeft(left);
        bp.setRight(right);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 600, 400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("main.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

MasterController.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class MasterController {

    private static VBox rightBox;
    private static BorderPane root;

    public static VBox getRightBox() {
        return rightBox;
    }

    public static void setRightBox(VBox rightBox) {
        MasterController.rightBox = rightBox;
    }

    public static BorderPane getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    public static void setRoot(BorderPane root) {
        MasterController.root = root;
    }
}
```

LeftController.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;

import java.io.IOException;

public class LeftController extends MasterController {

    @FXML
    public void loadCenter(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("center.fxml"));
                Parent center = loader.load();
            getRoot().setCenter(center);
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

CenterController.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class CenterController extends MasterController {

@FXML
private VBox center;
    public void initialize() {
        Platform.runLater(this::build);

    }

    public void build() {
        center.getChildren().add(new Text("loaded"));

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
        Text text = new Text("ROLL OVER");

        stackPane.getChildren().add(text);
        center.getChildren().add(stackPane);

        stackPane.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            getRightBox().getChildren().clear();

            Pane pane1 = new Pane();
            Text exampleText1 = new Text("Example Text");
            pane1.getStyleClass().add("blueBG");

            Pane pane2 = new Pane();
            Text exampleText2 = new Text("Example Text");
            pane2.getStyleClass().add("blueBG");

            pane1.getChildren().add(exampleText1);
            pane2.getChildren().add(exampleText2);

            pane1.setLayoutY(event.getSceneY() + 40);
            pane1.setLayoutX(event.getSceneX() - 40);

            getRoot().getChildren().add(pane1);
            getRightBox().getChildren().add(pane2);
        });
    }
}
```

RightController.java
    package sample;

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class RightController extends MasterController {

@FXML
private VBox rightBox;

    public void initialize() {
        setRightBox(rightBox);

    }
}
```

left.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.LeftController">
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loadCenter" prefHeight="38.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Click me to load center" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

center.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox fx:id="center" alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="200.0" stylesheets="@main.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.CenterController">
   <children>
      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Center" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

right.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox fx:id="rightBox" alignment="TOP_CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="200.0" stylesheets="@main.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.RightController">
   <children>
      <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Right Box" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

main.css

```
.blueBG {
    -fx-background-color: aqua;
}
```

You should get the following result. You can see the pane is being styled correctly when added to the right, but not when added too the root.

[image]

Comment: Show the css stylesheet. There may be a different rule with precedence over your "blue" rule.

Comment: I have the same issue when I literally only have: .blueBG{-fx-background-color: #374968; } in the entire sheet.

Comment: Reproduced it in a barebones application will edit in the files

Comment: I've editted in the files that should allow you to reproduce the issue. Really appreciate it if you could have a look @fabian.

Comment: Solved it - needed to change the root to a stackPane with the BorderPane added followed by a transparant Node to act as an overlay, which I then add stuff onto.

Comment: You misspelled "defense" (just throwing in some help for you there).

Comment: @PhilipVaughn As an Englishman I'll defend the queens English until the day I die. ;)

Comment: Haha! Fair fair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BorderPane` only applies layout to the `center`, `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` children. It's however the parent of a layout (or the scene in case of a root) that sets the size of a `Region` during a layout pass (or not, like in this case).

The result is that the style is applied to the `Pane`, but the size of the `Pane` remains `0`. You can verify this by adding

```
pane1.resize(100, 100);
```

to the event handler to set the size of the pane.

You need to use a different kind of layout as parent for `pane1`'s size to become non-empty or resize it yourself.